# Unable to build apk in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am running `flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./build/info` to build android apk

How can I fix the following error?

> Running "flutter pub get" in myapp...
> 1.0s You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64. If you are deploying the app
> to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the
> APK to reduce the APK size.
> To generate an app bundle, run:
> flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
> Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
> To split the APKs per ABI, run:
> flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
> Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
> Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar,
> > org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Projects\myapp\myapp\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.
> > > Transform's input file does not exist: C:\Projects\myapp\myapp\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.
> > (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 19s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done
> 79.8s Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification in your `build.gradle`(app level)

```
lintOptions {
     // Code...
     checkReleaseBuilds false
     // Added the above line so that 'flutter build apk' could work
}
```

**See this issue on Github**

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247

**My solution is based on this comment** (This one worked for me)
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247#issuecomment-636253593

**This comment provides some depth on the issue**
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247#issuecomment-636500680

Comment: @asad-hamed after adding `checkReleaseBuilds false`, I can build apk file, but when I install it, we have just a white screen

Comment: Run the app on emulator and check the `logcat` to see what's wrong.
Share the error in the log, I might be able to help you :)